# How to have different proxy configuration for a Model and a Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Probably the question's title is not very well-formulated. Anyway;

Let's say I have a Model defined as:

```
Ext.define('App.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    // etc
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/someurl',
        appendId: false, // this is set to false just because of the TreePanel behavior
    }
}
```

And a TreeStore using this Model definition:

```
Ext.define('App.store.MyModelTreeStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires : [ 'App.model.MyModel' ],
    alias : 'store.mymodeltreestore',
    model : 'App.model.MyModel',
    storeId : 'mymodeltreestore',

    root : {
        expanded : true
    },

});
```

In this model, the proxy has a property `appendId` set to `false` because this model is used to populate a `TreePanel`, which as default behaviour, the `TreePanel` appends `root` to the URL when loading the resources from the server (`/someurl/root`), which is not REST compliant. When loading all the resources in REST, it should make a `GET` request to `/someurl` and that's all, while when it should load a specific resource, append its id to the end of the URL, like `/someurl/307`.

The plot thickens when I need to get a specific resource from the server using this model definition, as in `App.model.MyModel.load(307, { success: function(){ // some callback }}`, because as `appendId` is `false`, ExtJs will `GET /someurl?node=307` instead of `GET /someurl/307`!

So finally, the question is: How to overcome this problem? How can I configure just the `TreeStore` to not append the id to the URL? In other words, how can I make the store's proxy inherit from the model's proxy, but have its own definitions, without messing with the model?

Answer (score 0):

My (not optimal) solution was to create a `App.model.MyModelTree` which extends `App.model.MyModel`, with the difference of adding `appendId: false` to its proxy settings, and make the `TreeStore` use this model instead of the original.

```
Ext.define('App.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    // etc
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/someurl',
    }
}
Ext.define('App.model.MyModelTree', {
    extend : 'App.model.MyModel',

    proxy : {
        type : 'rest',
        url :'/someurl',
        appendId : false,

    }
});
```

This is a dirty solution and I don't agree with the idea of specifying a new model for special use with the tree. I think Sencha should review the `TreePanel` urgently as I remember having this problem since ExtJS 4.

Comment: I expect someone else to post a better solution which I can accept as an answer, because I won't mark this one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify new proxy in the store configuration. It will override the model's proxy property.

```
Ext.define('App.store.MyModelTreeStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires : [ 'App.model.MyModel' ],
    alias : 'store.mymodeltreestore',
    model : 'App.model.MyModel',
    storeId : 'mymodeltreestore',

    root : {
        expanded : true
    },
    proxy: {
        type : 'rest',
        url :'/someurl',
        appendId : false,
    }
});
```